# Integrating Okta via a Authorization Filter

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, okta

I have implemented Okta authentication into my asp.net core application via this tutorial:

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/04/20/dotnet-6-web-api

This is perfect for my SPA to authenticate with my api. However, there are different user types for accessing my API and this information is passed in the claims. I am trying to create a filter to make it very easy to implement for each endpoint I want to give access to. I have created a general filter and it works great but I do not pass any parameters:

```
public class OktaAuthorizeFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly Okta.IJwtValidator _validationService;

        public OktaAuthorizeFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IJwtValidator validationService)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _validationService = validationService;
        }

        public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var authToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext!.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken))
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(string.Empty);
                return;
            }

            var validatedToken = await _validationService.ValidateToken(authToken.Split(" ")[1]);

            if (validatedToken == null)
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(string.Empty);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public class OktaAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public OktaAuthorizeAttribute() : base(typeof(OktaAuthorizeFilter))
        {
        }
    }
```

This works great as follows:

```
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetUserAccount")]
    [OktaAuthorizeAttribute]
    [EnableRateLimiting("api")]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        UserAccount TestAccount = new UserAccount() {InternalUserNumber = 3, EmailAddress = "test@mail.com"};
        var json = _userAccountService.Read(TestAccount);
        return Ok(json);
    }
```

To differentiate my user types the Okta JWT token has a claim that lists the user types. A user could be Type1 and Type2 or just Type1, etc. So I was hoping to implement my filter similar to how ms graph works as follows:

```
[OktaAuthorizeAttribute(Type = new string[] { "Type1", "Type2" })]
```

This way if a user satisfies one of these options then it will work. I am not sure however how to pass parameters to the filters to make this work and then how can I use them? Is this level of authorization possible?

EDIT 3/28/24

I have updated my code to the following and it runs but unfortunately it runs after my controller runs so it doesnt restrict access. Not sure why!

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using ARMS_API.Okta;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace ARMS_API.Filters
{
    public class OktaAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly string[]? _permissions;
        private readonly Okta.IJwtValidator? _validationService;
        public OktaAuthorizationFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, Okta.IJwtValidator validationService, string[] Permissions)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _validationService = validationService;
            _permissions = Permissions;
        }
        public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var authToken = context.HttpContext!.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

            //ensure that acccess token has data
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken) || _validationService == null)
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(string.Empty);
                return;
            }
        
            var validatedToken = await _validationService.ValidateToken(authToken.Split(" ")[1]);

            if (validatedToken == null)
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(string.Empty);
                return;
            } 

            var RoleClaim = validatedToken.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type.ToString() == "role").FirstOrDefault();
            
            if(RoleClaim == null)
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(string.Empty);
                return;
            }
            
            var roles = RoleClaim.Value.Split(',');

            if(roles.Intersect(_permissions!).ToArray().IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(string.Empty);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public class OktaAuthorizationAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public OktaAuthorizationAttribute(params string[] Permissions) : base(typeof(OktaAuthorizationFilter))
        {
            Arguments = new object[] { Permissions };
        }
    }
}
```

And now the attribute shows like this above the controller:

```
[OktaAuthorization("usertype1", "usertype2")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to utilize this approach to using a filter with parameters set by a attribute and filter you need to ensure you utilize the Arguments parameter as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using APP.Okta;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace APP.Filters
{
    public class OktaAuthorizationFilter : IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private readonly string[]? _permissions;
        private readonly Okta.IJwtValidator? _validationService;
        public OktaAuthorizationFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, Okta.IJwtValidator validationService, string[] Permissions)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _validationService = validationService;
            _permissions = Permissions;
        }
        public async void OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var authToken = context.HttpContext!.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

            //ensure that acccess token has data
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken) || _validationService == null)
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(string.Empty);
                return;
            }
        
            var validatedToken = await _validationService.ValidateToken(authToken.Split(" ")[1]);

            if (validatedToken == null)
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(string.Empty);
                return;
            } 

            var RoleClaim = validatedToken.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type.ToString() == "roles").FirstOrDefault();
            
            if(RoleClaim == null)
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(string.Empty);
                return;
            }
            
            var roles = RoleClaim.Value.Split(',');

            if(roles.Intersect(_permissions!).ToArray().IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(string.Empty);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public class OktaAuthorizationAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public OktaAuthorizationAttribute(params string[] Permissions) : base(typeof(OktaAuthorizationFilter))
        {
            Arguments = new object[] { Permissions };
        }
    }
}
```

THen to utilize the variable as a parameter in the attribute tag do as follows:

```
[OktaAuthorization("usertype1", "usertype2")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Few thing here need changes - you can resolve your dependencies form `HttpContext.RequestServices` with in the  `AuthorizationFilterContext`, so no need to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` since you already have `HttpContext`.

You can pass parameters to your attribute like this :

```
public class OktaAuthorizeFilter : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public string[] Items;
        private readonly Okta.IJwtValidator _validationService;

        public OktaAuthorizeFilter()
        {
        }

        public async void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var authToken = context.HttpContext!.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken))
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(string.Empty);
                return;
            }
            _validationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<Okta.IJwtValidator>();
            var validatedToken = await _validationService.ValidateToken(authToken.Split(" ")[1]);

            if (validatedToken == null)
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedObjectResult(string.Empty);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can use it :

```
[OktaAuthorizeAttribute(Items = ["Type1", "Type2"])]
```

Not sure why do you use the `IAuthorizationFilter` when the use of `AuthorizationHandler` is so flexible - maybe something to consider in the future. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how do I access Items? I dont see it utilized anywhere other than a variable named Type but that is not defined anywhere? Also, Authorization Handler allows for built in logic similar to what I am trying to do? I have used authorization tag before with entity framework but to use in this context wouldn't I need a custom middleware?

Comment: @IrishRedneck sorry had a typo in OktaAuthorizeFilter , you have a property Items in OktaAuthorizeFilter  - does this help ?

Comment: Oh so Items variable in OktaAuthorizeFilter automatically is assigned the Items from the attribute property? How does it know that? Sorry these may be dumb questions but I wouldnt have assumed I could just do this .

Comment: Well attributes allow assigning values to public properties.  If items were private you wouldn't be allowed to do this. You can look at the [OktaAuthorizeAttribute(Items = ["Type1", "Type2"])] like this : new OktaAuthorizeAttribute() {Items = ["Type1", "Type2"]}

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand that. Makes perfect sense now!

Comment: Finally got to try this out and unfortunately for Items in my controller it states "The type or namespace name 'Items' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"